# Почему не работает всплывающее окно с видео для кнопки?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, всплывающее-окно

Есть видео, которое проигрывается в всплывающем окне скрипта **magnificPopup** 
Вопрос: почему при нажатии на ссылку всплывающее окно появляется и видео проигрывается - все хорошо, а при нажатии на кнопку нет? как сделать так, чтобы и по нажатии на кнопку все работало? [Вот фидл](http://jsfiddle.net/vGAsL/67/)

```js
    $(".play-single").magnificPopup({
      type: "iframe"
    });

    $("#inpage_scroll_btn").magnificPopup({
      type: "iframe"
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://rawgithub.com/dimsemenov/Magnific-Popup/master/dist/jquery.magnific-popup.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://rawgit.com/dimsemenov/Magnific-Popup/master/dist/magnific-popup.css">
<a href="https://vimeo.com/80836225" class="play-single">Play Single</a>
<br/>
<br />
<button id="inpage_scroll_btn" class="btn btn-primary standard-button inpage-scroll" onclick="parent.location='https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DLihUyElkhM'">СМОТРЕТЬ</button>
```

Comment: magnificPopup скорее всего использует this для получения ссылки, надо передать ей контекст

Comment: @splash58 спасибо, но "скорее всего" меня не устроит - мне нужно задачу решить)

Comment: я бы как-то так сделал `$("#inpage_scroll_btn").click(function() { $(".play-single").click(); })
    });

Comment: ну так попробуй предложенный вариант

Comment: @splash58 привет невидимые зависимости)))

Comment: @splash58 да, что-то вы не то предлагаете, к тому же не рабочее..

Comment: @Вася -  в чем он не рабочий ? -  http://jsfiddle.net/sqo6qppd/1/

Comment: @splash58 аа, там была лишняя закрывающая скобка, но правильный ответ внизу, т.к. я собираюсь уйти от зависимости ссылки и вообще от нее отказаться

Comment: дело ваше. но мне кажется, что чем на 100 видео иметь 100 разных функций на js, правильнее написать универсальный код и хранить данные, например. в тех же ссылках

Comment: @splash58 для 100 видео гораздо лучше кнопку на ссылку сразу поменять) мне нужно просто 1 видео, которое если и поменяется, то раз в жизни)

Answer (score 2):

Решение до боли простое - убрать атрибут onclick с кнопки и `src` вставить в параметры плагина - [фидл](http://jsfiddle.net/sqo6qppd/)